# Python Random Color Generation using Turtle

Tags: python, random, colors, turtle-graphics

I need to generate a random color using r g b values to fill in these rectangles for a python school assignment, I'm getting a bad color sequence error even though I'm fairly sure I'm formatting it just as the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.color) suggests.

```
r = random.randrange(0, 257, 10)
g = random.randrange(0, 257, 10)
b = random.randrange(0, 257, 10)


def drawRectangle(t, w, h):
    t.setx(random.randrange(-300, 300))
    t.sety(random.randrange(-250, 250))
    t.color(r, g, b)
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        t.forward(w)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(h)
        t.right(90)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
```

I'm quite confused as to why t.color(r, g, b) is not producing a random color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[turtle.colormode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.colormode) needs to be set to 255 to give color strings in Hex Code or R G B.

adding

```
screen.colormode(255)
```

no longer returned an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables r g and b are not global. You either have to add a global declaration at the top of your function or add them as parameters.

```
def my_function(r, g, b):
    # some stuff
```

Or...

```
def myfunction():
    global r, g, b
    # some stuff
```

Comment: How would I go about adding them as parameters?

Comment: In drawRectangle, you already have parameters: t, w and h. Just add them to that list in between the brackets. :)

Comment: Thanks, the global variables makes sense now, but I'm still getting an incorrect color sequence error, even if I just put in integers for r, b, b. t.color(100, 150, 200) still returns a bad color sequence error, is some other formatting wrong?

Comment: The error wouldn't be with the globals then. There could be something wrong with the colours themselves. I don't work with colours or turtle or anything, but that's the impression I get.

Comment: Thanks for your help as it did give me a better understanding of variables and parameters, but my problem lied in turtle.colormode which I outlined in my answer below.

Comment: Great! Mark your's as the accepted one then too. :)